# How to add more than 2 variables in K nearest neighbour regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, knn

This is my code for 2 variables in a knn regression:

```
X = df[['Health index', 'Number of PHYSICIAN']]
y = df['Mortality rate']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
neigh = neighbors.KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=5).fit(X_train, y_train)

sample = [1000, 1000]
sample_pred = neigh.predict([sample])
print('Mortality rate:', int(sample_pred),'%')

y_pred = neigh.predict(X_test)
mse = metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
print('Root mean squared error (RMSE):', sqrt(mse))
print('R-squared score:', metrics.r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Is it possible to use more than 2 variables in a knn regression, and if so, how? When I try to fit 3 variables this error message shows up and I dont know where to fix it.

```
ValueError: X has 2 features, but KNeighborsRegressor is expecting 3 features as input.
```

Comment: If Aleksander's answer helped you, remember to upvote and/or mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly fine to use more than 2 variables with KNN regressor.

If you want to do so, simply add more columns to your `X`:

```py
X = df[['Health index', 'Number of PHYSICIAN', 'feature 3', 'feature 4', ...]]
```

**Note**: You should normalize your variables in `X`, so they all have **similar scale** (otherwise some features might overweight other features impairing the learning process).

As @kwinkunks mentioned in the comment: when normalizing your features, it's important that you fit your normalizer/scaler on the training subset only and then transform training and test data (and validation data if relevant) using this normalizer/scaler. If you fit it on the whole dataset before splitting, you risk data leakage.

Also, you might want to consider if for your problem 5 neighbours is enough to **avoid overfitting**.

Comment: Good advice. And be sure to normalize (or standardize) X _after_ splitting. Fit the scaler to `X_train` only, then use it to transform your datasets.